# Is there a way to call Python script inside of a Kotlin project?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kotlin

I have been programming a Python desktop app in Python 3.7 with tkinter. Many of my friends have said using it as an mobile application will get more users. I have been working with sklearn and different modules in Python to run along side the GUI. Is it possible to call that script in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Python has REPL, it's own interactive interpreter and as it turns out Kotlin has a REPL as well. You'll still have to do research and find the interfaces to use with your front end.

NOTE: In Intellij Idea Kotlin has REPL. I'm afraid I don't know if it's the same with other IDEs.

If it's only for Android, you can use QPython.
QPython is a script engine which runs Python programs on android devices.

Comment: Okay thank you, that answers my question. If you know a lot about this kind of stuff, do you think you could answer another question(it won't let me post another one).

Comment: Is it possible to send data from an app on a phone to another phone? I'm sure there is, but do you know of the method?

Comment: I don't know a lot of it, but I may be able to help you with this.
There are a few questions I'd like to ask first though;
Do you want to send data to the same app on another phone?
Because if that's the case you can just make an interface that collects data from one user (after requesting and being granted with all the required permissions) and passes it on to another user.

Comment: Yeah but that wouldn't require any servers or anything? Would it just send over wifi or bluetooth. I'm sorry, I got away from mobile development a while ago, I went with AI and ML.

Comment: do you want this as a feature in your application? If not, you can just download data in a file and then share it via any sharing application.

Comment: and using an interface would require a server