# How to run a python function in kotlin?

Tags: python, android, kotlin

I am making an app in kotlin. But I know python a lot and made the logic in python. The kotlin is only used for the display. Is there a way to call a python function in kotlin?. A  python script can call python scripts but can a Kotlin script call one?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898765/calling-python-in-java. Kotlin should be the same as Java for the purposes of this question (unless you are using Kotlin/JS, in which case look for calling Python from Javascript instead).

Comment: I am using Kotlin as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Again, this won't make a difference. The answers for every JVM language will be the same.

Comment: I found a post that says REPL helps. But there is not much information on the web.          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021771/is-there-a-way-to-call-python-script-inside-of-a-kotlin-project

Comment: I couldn't find one for JVM

Comment: I am now very confused on what to do...

Comment: I am quite sure that answer is wrong and having a REPL doesn't help with calling Python in any way.

Comment: Yes, REPL is not widely used too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two normal solutions.

1. Using Polyglot API of GraalVM (https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/package-summary.html).
2. Creating a C interface implemented with Python (https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497) and calling it with JNI (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/). However, this option needs you to manage your objects and memory very carefully (dispose all C pointers properly etc.)

Comment: Foreign Function Interface (FFI) features are not for beginners.

Comment: Consider using simple network protocols like HTTP or WebSocketts

Comment: If the Python library provides a CLI, simply call that via `executeCommand()`?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution – Chaquopy

https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/

Works for me